# list-formatter called several times

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dropdown

I have a list-formatter (autocompleListFormatter) which is called several times when the dropdown is initiated.

[image]

The image above shows the output from the console, after the dropdown is initiated only once.

**dropdown.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" class="">
  <div class="form-style">
    <input
      autofocus
      [list-formatter]="autocompleListFormatter"
      type="text"
      class="form-control"
      formControlName="gridDropdown"
      [source]="dropdownData"
      value-property-name="id"
      display-property-name="name"
      [(ngModel)]="value"
    />
  </div>
</form>
```

**dropdown.component.ts**

```
export class DropdownComponent implements OnInit, AgEditorComponent {
  @Input() name: String;
  public dropdownData = ColumnData[0].cellEditorParams.values;
  public myForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private builder: FormBuilder, private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

// ****DROPDOWN****** //
  autocompleListFormatter = (data: any) => {
    console.log('autocompleListFormatter..............');
    let html = `<span>${data.name}</span>`;
    return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
  };

  agInit(params: ICellEditorParams) {
    this.value = params.value;
    this.oldValue = this.value;
    this.value = '';
    return this.value;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.builder.group({
      gridDropdown: ''
    });
  }
}
```

**column-data.ts**

```
export let ColumnData = [
  {
    editable: true,
    cellEditor: 'editComp',
    cellEditorParams: {
      values: [
        { id: 1, name: '200001 - General Management' },
        { id: 2, name: '200002 - Management' },
        { id: 3, name: '200003 - DataCenter' },
        { id: 4, name: '200009 - Location Hamburg' },
        { id: 5, name: '200010 - General Management' },
        { id: 6, name: '200011 - Management' },
        { id: 7, name: '200012 - DataCenter' },
        { id: 8, name: '2000213 - Location Hamburg' }
      ]
    }
  }
];
```

Is there any way to avoid this? Should I be using a specific lifecycle hook or something else?

Answer (score 2):

According to the number of items present in the values array of the ColumnData the filter is called on each time to create the span for drop down that number of time .

You can see that in Chrome combines the log count that is 8

Comment: Thanks, Yes - the log count is 8 but this happens 10 times when the dropdown is initiated only once. Is this acceptable?

Comment: May be it is getting binded and rebinded in angular

Comment: Im really not sure if it is getting rebinded. Is there anyway to confirm this?

Comment: You are saying that it runs total of 80 times